# Java terminology check

Tags: java

With my common programming knowledge, along with some research, I know these terms to mean as follows:

1. Declaration: `int x;`
2. Initialisation: `x = 0;`
3. Instantiation: `Night n = new Night();`
4. Declaration and initialisation can be done together: `int x = 0;`
5. Instantiation and initialisation can be done together: `b = new JButton("this is a button");`

Are these correct?

Comment: `x = 0` is *assignment*, not initialization. It's only initialization when done in the declaration statement. --- #3 and #5 overlaps. *Instantiation* should only be `new Night()`. *Then* #5 is both instantiation and assignment, while your #3 is declaration, instantiation, and initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the most part. For the last statement, however, it is both an instantiation and an initialization, as the instantiation initialized the variable, b.